# Javascript round to Closest Biggest value

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to change `8.34 to 8.4, 27.62 to 27.7 (not 27.6)` i came with code so far

```
var a = 3.34
a.toFixed(1) // 8.3 the result i need is 8.4
var b = 27.62 // 2.7 this correct
```

tried using several function like `round()` or `Math.floor()`, i know the result should be 8.34 if we round it 8.3 because it's not 8.35, but can we make 8.34 become to 8.4 ?

Comment: Or: [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by 10, use `Math.ceil`, and then divide by 10:

```js
const convert = num => console.log(Math.ceil(num * 10) / 10);
convert(8.34);
convert(27.62);
```

Comment: Wow, wow I don't think it's so simple, thanks man it's work, i need learn more about JS.

Comment: @KhairuAqsara That's why you're not the first one asking that question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```js
let a = 8.34;
let b = 27.62;

console.log(Math.ceil(a*10)/10)
console.log(Math.ceil(b*10)/10)
```